# How to use the OR condition in when clause of SQL Loader control file

Tags: sql-server, sql-loader, ctl, controlfile

I am trying to use the OR condition in when clause in control file, This this my code in control file :

```
load data
INFILE 'router.txt'
INTO TABLE ROUTER_ATTLAS_TABLENAME  
APPEND
**WHEN ((1) = 'J' or  (1) = 'D2'  or  (1) = 'vJ' or  (1) = 'VJ' )**
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\|'
```

I am getting a error :SQL*Loader-350: Syntax error at line 5.

```
Expecting ")", found "or".
WHEN ((1) = 'J' or  (1) = 'D2'  or  (1) = 'vJ' or  (1) = 'VJ' )
```

Please suggest me an  correct syntax.

Comment: I don't think APPEND is to be used here. Check the correct syntax for [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)

Comment: I saw in one website , They have used 'and ' condition in  WHEN clause

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid OR is not allowed in a WHEN clause: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_control_file.htm#i1005657

Answer (score 0):

You just need two "insert" command in the same table.
Copy...

INTO TABLE ROUTER_ATTLAS_TABLENAME
APPEND
**WHEN ((1) = 'J' or  (1) = 'D2'  or  (1) = 'vJ' or  (1) = 'VJ' )**
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\|'

using different WHEN to each desired one.